Error when integrating Spline3D Model into React Three Fiber
I made a model using Spline3D, and downloaded the react-three/fiber code directly from the site. When I integrate it into my React website, I'm getting the following errors:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: UseRef
The above error occurred in the  component:
CoffeeCorner@http://localhost:5173/src/models/CoffeeCorner.jsx:21:23
Suspense
Suspense
ErrorBoundary@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LZ7Z3UXZ.js:45832:10
FiberProvider@
Provider@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LZ7Z3UXZ.js:47119:8

This is the code (the beginning part) for my 3D Model:
  import useSpline from "@splinetool/r3f-spline";
  import { OrthographicCamera } from "@react-three/drei";
  import { a } from "@react-spring/three";

  const CoffeeCorner = ({ ...props }) => {
  const CoffeeCornerRef = UseRef();
  const { nodes, materials } = useSpline(
    "https://prod.spline.design/RENFgTCetyHrlEpV/scene.splinecode"
  );
  return (
    <>
      <color attach="background" args={["#a9866b"]} />
      <a.group ref={CoffeeCornerRef} {...props}>
        <scene name="Scene">

This is the code for where I call the 3D model to be used:
import CoffeeCorner from "../models/CoffeeCorner";


const Home = () => {
  return (
    <section className="w-full h-screen relative">
      <Canvas
        className="w-full h-screen bg-transparent"
        camera={{ near: 0.1, far: 1000 }}
      >
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <directionalLight />
          <ambientLight />
          <pointLight />
          <spotLight />
          <hemisphereLight />

        <CoffeeCorner />
        
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </section>
  );
};```




The website will load for a second (without displaying the model, just the navbar and routing links) then blank. When I inspect the console, those are the errors it gives me.

